# What is the benefit of the one "DATE" datatype over another in Laravel/SQLite?

Tags: sql, laravel, sqlite

In my app, I'm just using a SQLlite database for development. Now in the migration, I declare a `DATE` datatype which laravel seems to handle without any problem, and in the database itself creates it as a `varchar`.

According to this nice article (http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-date/) SQLite has basically got three options for handling dates:

- Using the TEXT storage class for storing SQLite date and time Using
- REAL storage class to store SQLite date and time values
- Using INTEGER to store SQLite date and time values

So as I'm trying to formulate my approach, I'm thinking ahead that I will likely end up, at some point, need to step up and move to a higher performance SQL database (mySQL / Postgres / etc. ) And then may have datatype translation challenges.

But then also, at the application layer, Laravel itself has some manipulations.

Now, the question I'm asking is this, What is the benefit of one type over another? Is there some kind of reason to choose one type over another? My thinking is that TEXT is nice and human-readable for backend support, but it may require addiotnal coding to manipulate strings.

INTEGERS are probably more efficient, and would be translatable to a bigger SQL server easier than text.

Does anyone know of a comparison of the pro's and con's of various choices? 
Any advice? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you asking which type (`TEXT`, `REAL`, `INTEGER`) to use for dates?

Comment: Well, from what I'm reading, I can use all of them - with sqlite that is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The size of integer is 4 bytes.  The size of a letter in text is 1 byte.
To represent date and time you need 1 UTC number when you use integer. So its much better to user 4 bytes of integer than using 8 bytes of text. I dont see how real can be better than integer for the exact same reason. I would say you should use integer.

Comment: SQLite can store an integer in 1-8 bytes. Real is 8 bytes. [Datatypes In SQLite Version 3 - 2. Storage Classes and Datatypes](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)